# Adding non user field to payload for use in JWT token

Tags: javascript, node.js, jwt, feathersjs, feathers-authentication

Hi I'm looking to add a non user field to the payload in the auth process so I can included in the JWT token.

The request is like this:

```
{ "scriptId": "script1", "password": "password", "userName": "user1" }
```

config is like this:

```
  "auth": {
    "local": {
      "usernameField" : "scriptId"
    },
    "token": {
      "secret": "mysecret",
      "payload": ["scriptId","userName"],
      "expiresIn": "10min"
    },
    "successRedirect": "/chat.html"
  }
```

How can I pass the userName parameter so I can retrieve it in the before hook of the auth/token service so I can it to the hook.data

Or if there's a better way to do it just let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Check [this PR:](https://github.com/feathersjs/feathers-authentication/pull/80)

```
// default.json
{
  "auth": {
    "extraFields": [
      "email",
      "roles"
    ]
  }
}
```

The `extraFields` are fieldnames of your user object. So data that goes in the JWT needs to be provided by your user endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

you can add this in following way

```
app.service('authentication').hooks({
    before: {
      create: [
        authentication.hooks.authenticate(config.strategies),
        function (hook) {
         hook.params.payload = {
            userId: hook.params.user.userId,
            accountId: hook.params.user.accountId
          };
          return Promise.resolve(hook);
        }
      ],
      remove: [
        authentication.hooks.authenticate('jwt')
      ]
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

1. create an after hook called add_payload (or whatever u want) for service authenticate using the command 'feathers generate hook'
2. inside /src/service/authentication/index.js add inside the end of the export

app.service('/auth/local').after(hooks.after);

3. create index.js file in /src/service/authentication/hooks, the contents should look like:

`'use strict'
    const addPayload = require('./add_payload');
    const globalHooks = require('../../../hooks');
    const hooks = require('feathers-hooks');
    exports.after = {
    all: [addPayload()],
    find: [],
    get: [],
    create: [],
    update: [],
    patch: [],
    remove: []
    };`

4. inside the hook function... /src/service/authentication/hooks/add_payload.js

   `return function(hook) {
       hook.result.aa = "xyz"; // add whatever you want to the return here...
       hook.addPayload = true;
   };`